# HTML / CSS unwanted margin

Tags: html, css

I'm currently working on a nodejs / socket.io project. Somehow there's a margin ontop aligned, which is pushing the UI down. I can't seem to get rid of.

Does someone have a idea, what could cause this?

Link to the preview: http://pr0b.com:2000/

The username & password to authenticate are assigned so you guys could have a look.

[Link to the screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pT1T2.png)

Code which is causing the problem:

```
<div id="belowGame">
    <div id="chat-text"></div>

    <form id="chat-form">
        <input type="text" id="chat-input"></input>
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: your link isn't working..

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] (the code you provided doesn't count: it isn't complete) and put it in **the question itself** instead.

Comment: Its the `display: inline-block;` on your gameDiv

Comment: Listen to @LewisBrowne

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This issue which was causing the overflow was the `display: inline-block` which was added to the `.gameDiv`. Simply remove this CSS rule and you will get what you've asked for.

Comment: Thanks, found the issue. It was caused by the js code. gameDiv.style.display = 'inline-block';